# pdfbox: how to solve font (STSong-Light) problem when converting pdf to image?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using pdfbox 2.0.26 to convert pdf to image. The maven dependencies are as following.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
```

The program that I wrote is like

```
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("/path/to/sample.pdf");
        try(final PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(fin)){

            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer((doc));

            BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 300, ImageType.RGB);
            File myObj = new File("/path/to/sample.png");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myObj);
            ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, "png", fos);
            fin.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
```

It works fine on my macOS (although the fonts in the image is different from the one in the pdf), but the Chinese characters are lost when I run it on the linux server.

The source PDF file can be found here [the source file](https://alihealth-examination-isv-image.oss-cn-zhangjiakou.aliyuncs.com/test/chinese_sample.pdf). I detected the font using adobe reader, the result are pasted as following.
[image]

The resulting image file is like:
[image]

What shall I do to solve the problem? Thank you

Comment: Try installing a few Chinese fonts on that server. PDFBox will try to find one that is close.

Comment: On my computer it uses ArialUnicodeMS-Bold and AdobeSongStd-Light instead of the missing (not embedded) fonts.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you very much. The program handles another pdf file (which also has Chinese words, but using different font types) well, so I did not realized it's because Chinese fonts are missing on the server. After read your advices, I upload a little bit more Chinese fonts on the server, and pdfbox can find a proper substitute font to process the pdf file. Thank you again

Comment: Great to hear it works! I suggest you answer your own question, mention "PDFBox will try to find one that is close", and mention which actual fonts you installed. Alternatively you can also delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Tilman Hausherr's suggestion, I realized that when the specified fonts are not available, "PDFBox will try to find one that is close". My problem was that PDFBox failed to find one that is close enough to recognize the font on the pdf file. After I upload some Chinese fonts to the server (for linux os, the fonts are copied to /usr/share/fonts), the problem was solved. The font types I used belong to the company I'm working for, but I believe fonts such as SimSun will also work, just try it out.