# flying saucer itext 9.1.22 not rendering image in the pdf

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

We recently upgraded flying-saucer-itext from 9.1.15 to 9.15.22, and the images are no longer rendering. We are using Docusign 3.23 SDK to fetch the signature images and try to render those in our app.

This is some part of the code.

pom.xml is

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
      <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-itext5</artifactId>
      <version>9.1.22</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
          <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
          <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>     
      <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>     
      <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>     
      <version>1.3.30</version> 
</dependency>
.
.
.
 <docusign.sdk.version>3.23.0</docusign.sdk.version>
```

The code logic is (truncated for privacy concerns)

```java
import org.stringtemplate.v4.DateRenderer;
import org.stringtemplate.v4.ST;
import org.stringtemplate.v4.STRawGroupDir;
import org.stringtemplate.v4.StringRenderer;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
.
.
.
signatureImageStringEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureImage);
.
.
```

and rendering this in a .st (String template ST4) file

```
 <img src="data:image/gif;base64, signatureImageStringEncoded" alt="Signature" width="200" height="75"/>
```

I went back to the 9.1.15 package, and it is rendering the image as expected, but our deployment team is pushing to update it to 9.1.22.

I tried referring [to this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477065/using-flying-saucer-to-render-images-to-pdf-in-memory) but no luck.

**Update on 7/6/2023.**
I'm encountering an error in the section of the code that handles creating PDF files.

```
Error:  
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font 'STSong-Light,BoldItalic' with 'UniGB-UCS2-H' is not recognized.
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.createInitialFontMap(ITextFontResolver.java:469)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextFontResolver.<init>(ITextFontResolver.java:40)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:117)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.<init>(ITextRenderer.java:102)
    at com.oncor.corp.pete.api.services.pdf.PDFService.createPDFFromTemplate(PDFService.java:49)
```

Comment: Security concern of what library exactly? Or security concern in general?

Comment: I apologize. There was no security concern. Our deployment/app security team is pushing for that update. I have tried multiple things but have had no luck rendering the pdf image.

Comment: Version 9.1.22 is still using an old version of openPDF. Try to exclude this version and use the latest one. `<exclusion>
    <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>    </exclusion>` and then import the latest one
`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.30</version>
</dependency>` And then try again...

Comment: @Lonzak, I updated my pom.xml on my thread based on your suggestion. Does that look correct?

Comment: Yes it looks correct. To be really sure check you final build for those dependencies: There should be only version 1.3.30 in there but not version 1.3.11. When that's the case then try again...

Comment: Font 'STSong-Light,BoldItalic' with 'UniGB-UCS2-H' is not recognized. I started receiving this error now. I've added the error trace to my original message @lonzak

Comment: You have to install the missing font. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73382606/pdfbox-how-to-solve-font-stsong-light-problem-when-converting-pdf-to-image)